# Find and classify singularities of the complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for my bad English. I have some problems in finding singularities of function

$f(z)=\frac{e^\frac{c}{z-a}}{e^\frac{z}{a}-1}$

I found that $z = a$ and $z = 0$ are singularities but i can't correctly classify them. And I think that I can lose some points because $c$ stay unused. Any suggestions how to
solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z=a$ is an  essential singularity since the function has infinitely many nonzero terms in its Laurent series expansion at $z=a.$  Note that $\frac{1}{e^\frac{z}{a}-1}$ is analytic at $z=a$ and remaining part $e^\frac{c}{z-a}$ has series expansion with infinitely many terms with negative powers of $(z-a)$ provided $c\neq 0.$
$z=0$ is the simple pole because the part $e^\frac{c}{z-a}$  is analytic at $z=0$ and the remaining part follows the following property,  $\lim_{z/a\rightarrow 0}\frac{z/a-0}{e^{z/a}-1}=1$

Comment: $z=0$ is a pole of order $1$.